# Prove how the algorithm works

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode, proof

Given the pseudocode

```
MUL(a,b) 
   x=a
   y=0
   WHILE x>=b DO
      x=x-b
      y=y+1
   IF x=0 THEN
      RETURN(true)
   ELSE
      RETURN(false)
```

I have to prove how the algorithm works.

So far I have only *explained* how it works, but I am not sure how you are supposed to *prove* how it works.

**Edit:** Just to clarify. I did ask [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40117582/proof-of-induction-on-pseudocode) question on another thread. But the two questions are separate. The assignment I am working on consists of 3 questions. The 1st question is where I explained how the algorithm works. The 2nd question is on my other [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40117582/proof-of-induction-on-pseudocode) and the 3rd question (this thread) is where I have to prove how the algorithm I explained in question 1 works. The reason why I asked this question is not to get the answer to the question, but simply an explationation as to what I am asked to do since I can't seem to figure it out myself. Personally I would just do the same as the 1st question, but that wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: What would that *explanation* be?  You haven't even said *what* it is supposed to accomplish, much less *how*.

Comment: You might also look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40117582/proof-of-induction-on-pseudocode). It seems remarkably pertinent.

Comment: that question was asked by the same user

Comment: Step 1 of the proof: remove all references to `y`

Comment: To clarify some things I edited the question.
@user3386109 That would leave me with only a and b (and x but that's pretty much the same thing as a). How would that help to prove the algorithm though?

Comment: The algorithm is based on the premise: `B divides A` *if and only if* `B divides (A-B)` for all `A>=B`. My proof of that would be, "Duh!". If you need a more formal proof, then [mathematics.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/) would be a better choice. BTW, proof by induction can work for this, but `x` and `y` are just distractions, so they should be removed.

Comment: @user3386109 Thanks, I'll try there. Hm, I don't think I'm supposed to use proof by induction since I was asked to use it in the previous question (the one linked in my edit)

Comment: I hope I'm not missing something obvious but did you mean y = y + b?

Answer (score 2):

Try to show the Pre-condition and Post-condition of the algorithm. Pre-condition predicates the initial state before execution and Post-condition predicates the final state after execution.

> The algorithm is correct if it can be proved that if the pre-condition is true, the post-condition must be true.

check this out for more details: [prove how algorithm works](http://www.cs.loyola.edu/~lawrie/CS295/F08/lectures/295-8.pdf)